# Shorthand selector invokation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have following objective c code:

```
if (isAppVisible) {
    [self hideApp];
} else {
    [self showApp];
}
```

Can it be reduced to something like
`[self isAppVisible ? @selector(hideApp) : @selector(showApp)]`
or any thing equivalent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[self performSelector:(isAppVisible ? @selector(hideApp) : @selector(showApp))];
```

but please don't: the if/else is way more readable.

Comment: @Fogmeister I totally agree, added a note